# How do I fix the 'MakeRenderPipelineState failed' error in RealityKit/ARKit?

Tags: swift, anchor, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to learn world anchors and I'm not able to place an object on tap. I'm getting the following error on startup:

```
2020-02-12 11:06:20.027274+0000 Project[8336:1778069] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-02-12 11:06:20.027756+0000 Project[8336:1778069] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-02-12 11:06:20.428611+0000 Project[8336:1778069] Compiler failed to build request
2020-02-12 11:06:20.428933+0000 Project[8336:1778069] [Graphics] makeRenderPipelineState failed [output of type ushort is not compatible with a MTLPixelFormatR16Float color attachement.].
2020-02-12 11:06:20.428995+0000 Project[8336:1778069] [Graphics] makeRenderPipelineState failed.
```

The app loads fine but I believe the makeRenderPipelineState failure could be what's holding me back. I've tried looking up for the error online but none of them seem to relate to what's in my code. Any ideas on how to fix this or what could be the problem? Cheers.

Code:

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Project
//
//  Created by Callum King on 11/02/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Callum King. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)



        setupARView()

        arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:))))


    }

    //MARK: Setup Methods

    func setupARView(){
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.session.run(configuration)

    }

    //MARK: Object Placement

    @objc
    func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: arView)

        let results = arView.raycast(from: location, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)

        if let firstResult = results.first {
            let anchor = ARAnchor(name: "toy_robot_vintage", transform: firstResult.worldTransform)
            arView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
        } else {
            print("ERROR: SURFACE NOT FOUND")
        }
    }

    func placeObject(named entityName: String, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        let entity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: entityName)

        entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        arView.installGestures([.rotation, .translation], for: entity)

        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
        anchorEntity.addChild(entity)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
    }
}

extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        for anchor in anchors {
            if let anchorName = anchor.name, anchorName == "toy_robot_vintage" {
                placeObject(named: anchorName, for: anchor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "AR Replay Data" enabled in the scheme?  I get this same error when trying to replay content from Reality Composer and only instantiating an ARView.

Comment: Explore commenting as a way to ask for valuable information. That way, others can jump in and relate yet we help the question stay as concise as possible.